# How to quickly save an unsigned char array to image file?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I have an array of unsigned char array which is actually a RGBA raw image. How to export it into the image file? Any image file format is OK.

Answer (score 1):

You can write it straight out as RGBA in binary. Then use ImageMagick, which is installed on most Linux distros, and available for OSX and Windows to convert it to `PNG` or something more common:

```
convert -size 300x400 -depth 8 binary.rgba result.png
```

You will need to tell ImageMagick the dimensions of the image as above because they are obviously not embedded within a raw file like they would be in a JPEG or PNG with a header.

If the filename you choose does not end in `.rgba`, you will need to prefix it with `RGBA:` like this

```
convert -size ... RGBA:something.bin result.png
```

If you are using OSX, I personally think `homebrew` is the easiest way to install ImageMagick...

```
brew install imagemagick
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is just saving it to a `.bmp` file, because basically bitmap is a (upside down) array of rgba values. So you can just write a simple header and then write it line by line to the file.

For a header you'd have to write the file header first, and after that there is the `DIB` header. There are multiple options for this, but i'd suggest the [simple one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#cite_ref-bmp_2-2).

The bitmap format has support for a lot of fancy stuff, but most of it is optional and for your propose not necessary.